# NoReverseMatch at error using Django/Python

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I am a beginner using django and python and I can't see any error in my code. Can you help me with my error. the process was to add a new data and will display in table after add.

[image]

Urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.conf import settings
from . import views
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns =[
path('',views.index, name='index'),
re_path('<int:am_ast>', views.view_asset, name='view_asset'),
path('add/', views.add_asset, name='add_asset',) 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import asset
from .forms import assetform

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'assetmanagement/index.html', {
        'assets': asset.objects.all()
    })

def view_asset(request, am_ast):
    ast = asset.objects.get(pk=am_ast)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

def add_asset(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = assetform(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            new_am_ast = form.cleaned_data['am_ast']
            new_sn = form.cleaned_data['sn']
            new_desc = form.cleaned_data['desc']
            new_acq_date = form.cleaned_data['acq_date']
            new_iss_date = form.cleaned_data['iss_date']
            new_emp_name = form.cleaned_data['emp_name']
            new_emp_dept = form.cleaned_data['emp_dept']
            new_scrp_name = form.cleaned_data['scrp_name']
            new_scrp_date = form.cleaned_data['scrp_date']
            new_loc = form.cleaned_data['loc']
            new_stat = form.cleaned_data['stat']
            new_rmks = form.cleaned_data['rmks']
            # new_img = form.cleaned_data['img']

            new_asset = asset(
                category= new_category,
                am_ast = new_am_ast,
                sn = new_sn,
                desc = new_desc,
                acq_date = new_acq_date,
                iss_date = new_iss_date,
                emp_name = new_emp_name,
                emp_dept = new_emp_dept,
                scrp_name = new_scrp_name,
                scrp_date = new_scrp_date,
                loc = new_loc,
                stat = new_stat,
                rmks = new_rmks,
                # img = new_img,
            )

            new_asset.save()
            return render(request, 'assetmanagement/add.html',{
                'form': assetform(),
                'success': True
            })
    else:
        form = assetform()
    return render(request, 'assetmanagement/add.html', {
        'form': assetform()
    })
```

index.html

```
 button type ='button' class="btn btn-success me-1" href="{% url 'view_asset' 
 asset.am_ast %}" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#vwModal{{asset.am_ast}}">
                            <i class="fa-regular fa-eye fa-lg"></i>
                            </button
```

Comment: change re_path to path in urlpatterns

Comment: @Razenstein path is my first code, I used re_path() coz I saw similar issue but still didnt run

Comment: Can you tell what's the setting APPEND_SLASH been set to? Also can you try adding a slash to your `index` path

Comment: Can you share your models?